# R : How to manage leaflet with Rmardown

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio

I get some difficulties with the (awesome) leaflet package (from rstudio) when I try to create a  Rmardown presentation. It works only when leaflet is in the first slide

The code below works fine:

````
## slide 1
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(leaflet)
m = leaflet() %>% addTiles()
m
```

## Slide 2 with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3
````

But the code below (where i just reverse slide 1 and slide 2) creates a leaflet openstreetmap with grey square in it :impossible to zoom and to see eventually added element (circle,polygon) **when I open it in a browser**:

````
## Slide 1 with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

## slide 2
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(leaflet)
m = leaflet() %>% addTiles()
m
```
````

Any ideas?